# WordPress "phpmailer_init" not working for me

Tags: php, wp-mail, phpmailer

I add the following code to the `functions.php` file.

```php
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example' );
function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host = SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->Port = SMTP_PORT;
    $phpmailer->Username = SMTP_USER;
    $phpmailer->Password = SMTP_PASS;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->From = SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName = SMTP_NAME;
}
```

and `wp-config.php`

```php
// SMTP email settings
define( 'SMTP_USER', '{email}' );
define( 'SMTP_PASS', '{password}' );
define( 'SMTP_HOST', '{server}' );
define( 'SMTP_FROM', '{from}' );
define( 'SMTP_NAME', '{name}' );
define( 'SMTP_PORT', '465' );
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'ssl' );
define( 'SMTP_AUTH', true );
```

"`wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`" when I go here, I enter my e-mail address and click the send button,

[image]

**"Failed to send e-mail. Your site may not be properly configured to send e-mail."** I am getting this error.

---

But when I paste the same code into another WordPress with WooCommerce plugin installed,
I forgot my WooCommerce password. Mail can be successfully sent from the front-end design.

Where is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

---

**3rd step**

```php
add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', function ( $error ) {
    error_log( $error->get_error_message() );
} );
```

Not working (IDK). But I searched and found the code below,

```php
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'log_mailer_errors', 10, 1);
function log_mailer_errors( $wp_error ){
  $fn = ABSPATH . '/mail.log'; // say you've got a mail.log file in your server root
  $fp = fopen($fn, 'a');
  fputs($fp, "Mailer Error: " . $wp_error->get_error_message() ."\n");
  fclose($fp);
}
```

**This gave me the following error**

```
Mailer Error: Invalid address:  (From): wordpress@localhost
```

I found the relevant location from `pluggable.php`.

Since I was working on localhost, it was emitting an invalid e-mail address because it did not create a valid TLD.

```php
        if ( ! isset( $from_email ) ) {
            // Get the site domain and get rid of www.
            $sitename = wp_parse_url( network_home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST );
            if ( 'www.' === substr( $sitename, 0, 4 ) ) {
                $sitename = substr( $sitename, 4 );
            }

            $from_email = 'wordpress@' . $sitename;
        }
```

This means, "`$phpmailer->From = SMTP_FROM;`" instead of "`add_filter ('wp_mail_from', 'set_from');`" should use.

```
function set_from()
{
    return 'name@domain.tld';
}

add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'set_from');
```

Works now.

> > I don't understand why `phpmailer_init` doesn't overwrite **from** information.

---

**By the way, the sender still appears to be what I defined in (`$phpmailer-> From`).**

**I guess this is some kind of bug and should be reported to WordPress?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Your code seems fine to me, so despite I can't give you a definitive answer on what/where exactly is the problem, I thought these might help you troubleshoot the issue:

1. First and foremost, check your configuration — e.g. did you use the correct (SMTP) username/email, password, host?

   And make sure the `SMTP_FROM` value is a valid **email addresss** — e.g. `user@example.com` and *not* `user@example` or `User <user@example.com>`; otherwise, the email will not be sent.
2. If you're sure the configuration is good, then because you're using SMTP, try enabling debugging like so — add this to your `my_phpmailer_example()` function:

   ```php
   // Note: I assumed you're using at least WordPress version 5.5.0

   $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
   ```

   Then visit the WordPress's password reset page and try to reset your password, and on the next page, if PHPMailer was unable to send the email, then you'd see the error message displayed at the top of the page.
3. If you can't do the SMTP debugging above (which is just a quick troubleshooting, actually), then enable [debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and use the [`wp_mail_failed` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_failed/) to try to catch any errors in sending the email — add this to the functions file:

   ```php
   add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', function ( $error ) {
       error_log( $error->get_error_message() );
   } );
   ```

   Then check the `wp-content/debug.log` file and see if there's any relevant errors/information.

### Update

(sorry, I couldn't resist from saying this) I liked this question and I'm glad that you managed to fix the issue. :)

> **I guess this is some kind of bug and should be reported to WordPress?**

Maybe, but it's definitely a good thing if they could do something to avoid the issue from happening, particularly because there are many folks who develop on `localhost`.

But just in case you're not aware of it, you could actually use virtual hosts like `localhost.dev` and that way, the issue could be avoided.

> Since I was working on localhost, it was emitting an invalid e-mail
> address because it did not create a valid TLD.

Yes, and I guessed you've already seen this note in the [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) code (in [`pluggable.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L328)):

```php
/*
 * If we don't have an email from the input headers, default to wordpress@$sitename
 * Some hosts will block outgoing mail from this address if it doesn't exist,
 * but there's no easy alternative. Defaulting to admin_email might appear to be
 * another option, but some hosts may refuse to relay mail from an unknown domain.
 * See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5007.
 */
```

So yes, either use the [`wp_mail_from` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_from/) or as I said above, use a virtual host.

> I don't understand why `phpmailer_init` doesn't overwrite **from**
> information.

Because WordPress/`wp_mail()` [calls `$phpmailer->setFrom()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L363) to set the `From` property and if PHPMailer throws an exception/error (e.g. due to invalid email address), then `wp_mail()` returns `false` and *never fires the `phpmailer_init` hook*.

But the `wp_mail_failed` hook does get fired, therefore it's a very good way to catch any errors which may occur when sending an email using `wp_mail()`. <sup>( and sorry, I didn't mention it [earlier](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/382729/2) because I thought the SMTP debugging would work for you as well :) )</sup>

> **By the way, the sender still appears to be what I defined in (`$phpmailer->From`).**

Yes, that's normal, because the `setFrom()` is called before the `phpmailer_init` hook is fired.

And actually, when I said "enable debugging in WordPress", I meant set both the `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` constants to `true`; and if `error_log()` doesn't write to `wp-content/debug.log` (or the file defined via the `WP_DEBUG_LOG` constant), then you could use the 2nd and 3rd parameters for `error_log()` like so:

```php
add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', function ( $error ) {
    // the "3" means write the message to the file as defined in the third parameter
    error_log( $error->get_error_message(), 3, WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
} );
```

But anyway, I hope this answer/update and the question also help someone else. =) Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry. I think I wrote it incomplete. Now I'm updating my question. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've revised my answer. Try the first two troubleshooting and whatever the result, let me know?

Comment: Thank you for giving a time. But the result is still negative.
SMTPDebug doesn't work because WordPress gives error message and stops the event before `$phpmailer->send()` function runs.
No plugins are installed. Also, the theme "twentytwentyone" is active. I tried it with a few other themes as well. It didn't work.

Comment: Try the 3rd step. And try also adding `error_log( 'my callback called!' );` in your `my_phpmailer_example()` function just to see if the callback is actually called. But if that 3rd troubleshooting doesn't help, your next step would probably be to contact the hosting support..

Comment: I forgot to ask, are you using WordPress 5.5+? Also if you can, try calling `wp_mail()` directly somewhere, e.g. in `admin_notices` hook and see if the function returns true and/or that the email gets sent. Try something super simple like: `wp_mail( 'you@domain.com', 'test', 'test' )`

Comment: I have version 5.6.1, I can try to send email manually and/or step 3. I will write down the results.

Comment: Sure, take your time.

Comment: the third step fixed the problem. I added a section under the above question explaining the operations. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: Glad I could help and have a look at the "Update" part in my answer. :) Cheers!